# docker-compose won't map container ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run two services using docker compose.  Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  data:
    build: ./ML_py
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
  node:
    build: ./node_server
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
```

This is all identical to the docker-compose beginner documentation, and when I run docker-compose up a network is created for the set of services. However, when I run docker ps, the containers have no mapped ports.  Shouldn't the port values specified by 'ports' take care of this?  Anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotes from the port mapping items? That's the only difference I can see between your compose file and their documentation (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#endpoint_mode)

Comment: @asdf Tried it and got the same result I'm afraid.  Other docs use double quotes when specifying ports.

Comment: Add the output of `docker-compose ps` and `docker ps`

Comment: Can you post the Network Setting -> Ports output of `docker inspect <container_name>`

Comment: @AllenMore were you able to find the solution? I don't think quotes matter. With or without should work.